# Send informations with AJAX, error "mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath="

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I use Javascript and AJAX to send some informations in a .NET MVC project. The code below works on my local machine but not on my server.

```
var str = "/Nouvelle_Fiche" + "/" + id_fiche + "/" + id_process + "/" + type_process + "/" + id_impact + "/" + id_auteur + "/" + id_situation + "/" + questionnaires;

xmlhttp.open("POST", str, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
```

I have an error "404 Not Found" with the line "xmlhttp.send();" because it add to my link "**mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath=**" so i have :
 "**mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/** Nouvelle_Fiche/17/13766/I/43/1162/1/2_"

Can you help me please ? Thank you !

Comment: You may need `https://<sitename>/<path>`... Also, shouldn't you be using `localhost://`

Comment: My complete link is "http://analyse..........com/mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/ Nouvelle_Fiche/17/13766/I/43/1162/1/2_"

Answer (score 0):

The main points MVC controller doesn't understand what you are trying to call. 
I believe your route config looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{process}/{typeprocess}/{impact}/{auteur}/{situation}/{questionnaires}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Nouvelle_Fiche", id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        process = UrlParameter.Optional, typeprocess = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        impact = UrlParameter.Optional, auteur = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        situation = UrlParameter.Optional, questionnaires = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

Assuming that Controller name is: **"Home"** and action is **"Nouvelle_Fiche"** which take 7 parameters

then your request should be like this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST",  @Url.Action("Home", "Nouvelle_Fiche", new { id = id_fiche, 
    process = id_process , typeprocess = type_process, 
    impact = id_impact, auteur = id_auteur, 
    situation = id_situation, questionnaires = questionnaires  }), true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send();
```